# How can I set proper file permission to developer in this setup?

Tags: php, linux

I am using Arch Linux on a web development machine, and have a multi-vhost setup with the root  directories of each vhost under:

```
/var/www/vhosts
```

Apache2 is using the user/group: http/http

If I setup the files to be owned by my user and the http group then apache cannot access them. If I setup the files to be owned by http and the users group then I have no access.

I am trying to move from a Windows development machine to Linux since right now I am doing PHP MySQL work.

How can I get around this issue so that my user can create and edit files without needing to worry about breaking access for apache each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Arch as well quite a lot and instead like the approach of using a limited user's home directory instead of /var/www/vhosts.  For instance, you could have a user named sites, ensure that they're not apart of any admin groups and then have the sites in /home/sites/site1, /home/sites/site2, etc… Then make sure that those directories are 644 and files 75:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0664 # For files
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755 # For directories
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Really like the idea. Only thing was I had to add sudo before since my user didn't yet have the rights to change the files!

Comment: Be sure to take that user out of the sudoer group- you never want to have a user with rights like that serving up files of any sort.